# Complicated tail recursion case

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, tail-recursion

Is it possible for the compiler to recognize tail-recursion in cases such as this?

```
void f(int x) {
    if (x == 1) {
        /* do_1... */
    }
    else if (x == 2) {
        /* do_2... */
    }
    else if (x == 3) { // here, we want do_2 and do_3; the order doesn't matter
        /* do_3... */
        f(2); // this should be tail recursive
    }
    else if (x == 4) {
        /* do_4... */
    }
}
```

Would placing a `return;` after `f(2);` help the compiler recognize it as a tail-recursion case?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the compiler output?  The answer to your question is very compiler specific, including version, optimization flags, etc.

Comment: You should not rely on a C++ compiler optimizing tail recursion. If correct behavior depends on not blowing up the stack, you should eliminate the recursion.

Comment: Also checking whether stack frame reuse is happening could be an option as well! :)

Comment: For this case in particular the call `f(2)` could in principle even be inlined, never mind tail recursion. Btw, consider `switch(x) { case 1: do_1; break; case 3 : do_3; /* fall through */ case 2: do_2; break; case 4: do_4;`

Comment: If a specific function is tail-recursive then it's always "possible" for a compiler to recognise it as such. I don't believe the question is meaningful.

Comment: @Anonymous well, then the question is whether (and why) this specific function is tail-recursive. I didn't know there was a definition of "tail recursive function"

Answer (score 0):

A compiler which recognizes opportunities for tail-call optimization should have no trouble recognizing it in that particular use case.